# Apache httpd.conf for redirecting ip to hostname

Tags: redirect, virtualhost, apache

I have external IP and hostname configured for my machine.

Inside the application, I am using only the domain names to access the APIs. So when i try to access my APIs through IP address, it shows 302 Moved temporarily error.
So, for request(for Homepage) that hits the server with IP address, It should redirect to hostname.

That is, when user hits https://XX.XX.XX.XX/main it should be redirected to https://ayz-abc.mysite.com/main

For this I tried using the redirect in httpd.conf of apache.

```
<VirtualHost XX.XX.XX.XX>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
#ServerName ayz-abc.mysite.com/

 # Other directives here
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule /.* https://ayz-abc.mysite.com/ [R]

</VirtualHost>
```

I have also tried with the following

```
<VirtualHost *.portnum>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule  https://XX.XX.XX.XX/main https://ayz-abc.mysite.com/main [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Plsssss help me.

Comment: 302 is not an error. If the server is responding with a 302 then the redirect is working. What is the HTTP response from the server?

Comment: The UI is still not redirected to the hostname, but the APIs are internally configured to point the hostnames. so when I try to access the APIs from UI, the request to APIs(with hostname) shows 302

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok. You are missing a rewrite condition

```
<VirtualHost XX.XX.XX.XX>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
#ServerName ayz-abc.mysite.com/

 # Other directives here
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^ayz-abc.mysite.com$
 RewriteRule /.* https://ayz-abc.mysite.com/ [R]

</VirtualHost>
```

If you don't include this condition it will redirect even with the hostname

Comment: That strips off the rest of the URL besides the HTTP_HOST. Better to use RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://ayz-abc.mysite.com$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 2):

This will redirect all request to IP to the similar on your domain

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^12\.34\.56\.78$

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$  https://ayz-abc.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule $ https://ayz-abc.mysite.com/ [L,R]
```

Also you can see rewrite logs, [see here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: I have tried using it but still getting the same error.
Also Ankit, in the browser, still it shows only the IP address.. Will it not be hostname ?

Comment: Redirect permanent https://xx.xx.xx.xx/main https://ayz-abc.mysite.com/main/ will it be ok?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Add the configurations in httpd.conf of apache

CASE-1: when user hits http://XX.XX.XX.XX/main or http://ayz-abc.mysite.com/main it should be redirected to https://ayz-abc.mysite.com/main

Configuration:

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName XX.XX.XX.XX
Redirect /main https://ayz-abc.mysite.com/main
</VirtualHost>
```

CASE 2 : When user hits https://XX.XX.XX.XX/main it should be redirected to https://ayz-abc.mysite.com/main

Configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
#Server Name 
ServerName XX.XX.XX.XX
SSLEngine on
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
# Redirect to the specified URL 
Redirect /main https://ayz-abc.mysite.com/main
<Directory />
SSLRequireSSL
</Directory>
....
....
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are NOT using API but just want browsers and crawlers to go to URL instead of an IP-Address, then you can use RedirectPermanent.

```
<VirtualHost XX.XX.XX.XX>

    RedirectPermanent / http://ayz-abc.mysite.com/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost XX.XX.XX.XX>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName ayz-abc.mysite.com/

</VirtualHost>
```

It has the advantage of responding with 301 HTTP status, which signals "please use the url you are redirected to in the future", which helps with search engines. You should use the same solution if you move your site to a new domain.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using **https** domain than add following:

```
# BEGIN HTTPS Redirection Plugin
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XX\.XX\.XX\.XX$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://your-domain-name.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END HTTPS Redirection Plugin
```

We are using https redirection plugin on site. Above block of code is generated by the plugin and we added only two lines in the code block. Below two lines are responsible to set IP to Domain redirection:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XX\.XX\.XX\.XX$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://your-domain-name.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Here **^XX.XX.XX.XX$** is your IP address, replace it like this: **^12.34.56.78$** with your server IP.

Thanks