# I want to block these 2 types of visitors to a site. How do I do this?

Tags: php, apache, security, symfony, ubuntu

I want to block these types of requests to my site. How is the best way to do it? I have listed what I have tried and my ideas so far.

I don't need any code just a pointer in the right direction.

I want to use the best method possible based on speed and I also don't want to block genuine people?

The site uses:

```
- PHP
- Symfony2
- Apache
- Ubuntu
```

I could easily do both of these in PHP, but thinking it may be better using Apache/Ubuntu etc.

(1) Block certain IP addresses. This would only be ones clearly doing something dodgy. E.g. a range of IP addresses from China if I have proven that all those IP addresses do is something dodgy.

I currently log the IP of every visitor. I later then manually look at this data and if I decide an IP (or range of) needs blocking I would then take manual action.

(2) Block anyone accessing my site by using the server IP address (e.g. 123.55.44.222) instead of the actual 'domain.com' domain name. I want to do this as it messes up the site (no doubt this could be resolved by changing my code, but nobody enters the IP so it's easier to do this).

With this I want a piece of code to detect if they are using the IP and just block them immediately (maybe return a 403 error)

Thanks.

Comment: The lower you get in the stack, the better is your performance. Blocking IPs using Apache should be ok for your use case (unless you own a very frequent and famous site which also gets attacked by botnets).

Comment: You may implement your own voter: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Block them at the firewall.
2. Either fix your site to not be broken when accessed via IP, or change apache's configuration to not serve it as the default site.

That aside, obsessively reading your logs and trying to block "people doing bad things" is going to drive you [further] into madness, and is generally pointless. You're going to whittle away your remaining free time and sanity playing whackamole with botnets, proxies, and script kiddies.

*Fix your code*. Address the fact that people are doing these "bad things" by removing their ability to do so.

Answer (score 1):

**[Spamhaus](http://www.spamhaus.org)** already maintains a [blacklist of IP addresses](http://www.spamhaus.org/drop/drop.lasso) and updates it every day. You can use [this script](http://www.debian-tutorials.com/iptables-shell-script-to-drop-spamhaus-listed-ip) to automatically fetch new list every day and update firewall to block the ip addresses.

If you wish to maintain your own blacklist, you can just replace the logic in the script that pertains to fetching from Spamhaus.

For second part of your question, you can do one of these

1. Redirect a user to the domain name based url, if ip address was used. [See this for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11651783/1243123)
2. Define a virtual host to match the ip address as the first virtual host. Here throw a HTTP 403 erro

Comment: Thanks. I later used the last line of your answer to go about a solution. My code is here if you are able to help further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412468/trying-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-to-block-access-by-ip-for-three-domains-and-when - thanks again.