# How to use a proxy/ Tunnelling VM to communicate between a user and APP Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

**Usecase-** An Angular and node js application is hosted on google app engine standard environment and it has been secured using an IP whitelist. How to use a static IP compute engine such that any user who has access to that compute engine only can open the APP engine link?

**Problem-** The IP of the user is dynamic and changes frequently throughout the day and hence it becomes an overhead to whitelist the new IP for every change in the IP.

**Ask-** How to use a compute engine such that it acts as a proxy to forward any request coming to **http://[compute-engine-public-ip]:80** to **xxxx.appspot.com**?

**Note-** Google APP engine IAP is not to be used because emails are not required.

Comment: You can create `f1-micro` VM instance with external static IP address as a part of [GCP Free Tire](https://cloud.google.com/free/), install there some HTTP web server like [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/),with or without authentication, [configure redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11651783/12428794) from `http://[compute-engine-public-ip]:80` to `xxxx.appspot.com`, then [configure firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) to allow access to your GAE app only from the external static IP address of VM  instance.

Comment: I guess that managing Google Cloud Firewall rule is as difficult as managing App Engine firewall rules. Why the VM instance solve your issue that you have with the constantly changing IP Address?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere you can always create a VM with a static IP, hence you won't have to manage the Firewall rules because a static entry would be added to it.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza that does makes sense, would it also work with [ssh port forwarding](https://superuser.com/questions/1345341/ssh-local-port-forwarding-to-a-website)?

Comment: *@john mich* I'm not sure about using SSH port forwarding for this use case. I'd recommend you to stick with some HTTP web server for redirect or, maybe, you can use some HTTP proxy.

Comment: @johnmich, I still don't understand! Ok, with a VM and a static IP, it's easy on App Engine to set a firewall rule on this static IP, problem solved on App Engine. But now, you have to accept connection from the user on your VM. And if their IP always change, how do you filter and accept only the correct users?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, I got what you're saying, for this I was planning to use [ssh port forwarding](https://superuser.com/questions/1345341/ssh-local-port-forwarding-to-a-website) so that this can be accessed using a socket to the VM and ssh keys. If there are 10 people with dynamic IPs there can be 10 port forwarding sequences right?

Comment: Ok, you want to open a SSH tunnel through the VM to jump to App Engine. Hmm, it's a complex deployment and I fear that it be weak. IAP is much more suitable for this. What's the issue with the emails?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere The client has issued around 10 emails but they are faulty and we are unable to add them to IAM groups. Even after adding them individually into the IAP permissions, they are not working for some around 4-5. Turns out these emails were formed differently from other emails and now they are not ready to change it. Hence, complexity. :(